# removing declined meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, meeting-request

I am running Outlook 2007.  When I send a meeting invite for a 1 on 1 and the person sends back a decline, how can I delete this meeting from my schedule without sending the person who declined a cancellation notice?

When I try to delete the meeting Outlook insists on sending a cancellation notice.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following VBA subroutine to delete appointments from my calendar.

```
Public Sub deleteSelectedAppointment()
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim cl As Integer
    Dim apt As AppointmentItem
    Dim aptDel As AppointmentItem
    Dim pattern As RecurrencePattern
    Dim cnt As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    cnt = 0
    For Each obj In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        cl = obj.Class

        Select Case cl
        Case olMail
        Case olTask
        Case olAppointment
            Set apt = obj
            Debug.Print "Appointment " & apt.subject

            If apt.IsRecurring Then
                '  find and delete the selected item in a series
                Set pattern = apt.GetRecurrencePattern()
                Set aptDel = pattern.GetOccurrence(apt.Start)
            Else
                '  non-recurring appointment
                Set aptDel = apt
            End If

            If aptDel Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Nothing to delete!"
            Else
                aptDel.Delete
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If

        Case Else
            Debug.Print "unexpected class " & cl
        End Select
    Next obj

    Debug.Print "Deleted appointments: " & cnt

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Cannot delete appointment" & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbInformation
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

It also works for tasks and mails. Obviously, such a routine might delete **a lot** if not used with care ...